# Filter data from pd.read_sql_query

Tags: python, sql

I'm using 'pd.read_sql_query' to extract the data from microsoft sql in python.
However, when I'm trying to filter specified row from the query, it show blank/ no result.

```
sql = pd.read_sql_query('''

                SELECT * FROM table
                       
                 ''', conn) 


df = pd.DataFrame(sql)


given = '02/03/2022'

given = datetime.strptime(given, '%d/%m/%Y')


dff = df[df['Date'] == given]

print(dff)
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Do you have your dates in the DB as dd/mm/yyyy??  Then that column is a string and you are comparing with a date. You should not store dates in DB in that way

Comment: Date in DB: dtype is date, and it is format as '%Y-%m-%d'. But if the `given` is put as '%Y-%m-%d' also no result show.

Comment: Some more comments, you don't need to do _df=pd.Dataframe(sql)_ because the return of read sql already is a DF. Try to do a df.head() and a df.info() to see how you have your data in DF. You may have it as strings in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' so you should need to convert it to dates or compare with a string

Comment: Checked with `df.info()`, dtype is object. Using `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')` to convert the `Date`, but still same, no result shown.

Comment: Because you are converting to datetime (that includes time). So don't convert and compare with string as 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: How about if I use `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce').dt.date` ? Will it only getting the date?

Comment: That should work too

Comment: But still unable to return the `df` data according to the selected date